# Why scala companion object's apply() returns Unit

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala.

```
class Student(var name:String, var age:Int) {
    private var sex:Int = 0
    println("class method")

    def apply() = {
       println("class apply method")
    }
}

object Student {
  def apply(name:String, age:Int): Unit = {
    println("object apply")
    new Student(name, age)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val student = Student("john", 29)
  }
}
```

`Student("john", 29)` in `main` supposes to give a `Student` but it returns `Unit`.

Any explanations would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overridden the behaviour of the default Student companion object generated by compiler by declaring your own Student companion object explicitly

```
object Student {
  def apply(name:String, age:Int): Unit = { //Here is the problem. Return type is Unit instead of Student
    println("object apply")
    new Student(name, age)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val student = Student("john", 29)
  }
}
```

Change your code to below code snippet

```
object Student {
  def apply(name:String, age:Int): Student = { //Changed the return type to Student
    println("object apply")
    new Student(name, age)
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val student = Student("john", 29)
  }
}
```

Comment: the scala compiler can detect this mistake by using the correct flag: -Ywarn-value-discard. other useful flags described here: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-compiler-review-code-warnings/

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is confusing, as `Student` is an ordinary class, not a case class.  So, there is no default companion object as there would be with a case class.